# how to convert world space transform to object space transform?

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, matrix, gl-matrix

i'm trying to implement :

[*transform.InverseTransformPoint(Vector3)*](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html) 
and
[*transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3)*](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformDirection.html) 
using glm library in opengl.
i have view ,projection ,model matrices for each object.

actually i don't know what i must to do with this matrices for got to that methods functionality.

Comment: Just use vector3 position objects in word space for transform to local space. Why you want to use matrices?

Comment: hi V. Borodinov , my object has been rotated and translated , cause of this , i need to calculate new position and rotation in new coordinate system.

Comment: Just need change basis matrices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, a point in local space can be transformed to NDC space by doing the following math:

```
Pworld = M * Plocal;
Pview = V * Pworld;
Pndc = P * Pview;
```

where M = model, V = view and P = projection.

So, if you have a point in world coordinate system and want to get it in local coordinate system, you just have to invert the first equation:

```
Plocal = inv(M) * Pworld;
```

This should be equivalent to `transform.InverseTransformPoint(Vector3)` (just add a fourth coordinate vector H = 1)

To implement `transform.InverseTransformDirection(Vector3)`, which is not affected by scale, you must use this equation:

```
Plocal = transpose(inverse(M)) * Pworld
```

where M is the upper-left 3x3 matrix from your original Model. To understand why you sould use this math, I invite you to look at this page: [normal transformation](http://web.archive.org/web/20120228095346/http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Illumination/Tut09%20Normal%20Transformation.html)

Comment: @Amadeus Isn't clip space an intermediate step between view and ndc?